# Drop down menu android non-spinner

Tags: java, android, android-studio, expandablelistview

I am trying to make a drop down menu as below *programmatically*
and don't want to use any spinner or xml:

[image]

[image: how to get this??[![][1]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtFWC.png)

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: Can you post your list item layout which you are using in adapter .

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **ExpandableListView** for fulfill your requirement

Answer (score 0):

There is a ton of libraries out there for this purpose.
Simply search for "Expandable Recycler View" and you will get what you need.

Here is my favorite : 
http://bignerdranch.github.io/expandable-recycler-view/

Comment: I m not able to find any ingredient class.

Comment: There is no Ingredient class in the library. The Ingredient class used in the library is a class used as an example and you need to apply the code for your own model.